# How to have MUI element within container reach browser window's edge

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI container with a Stack element within it, and within that I have two Box elements displaying as a row. These two boxes are set to 50% width taking up equal space.

[image]

What I am trying to do is have the second box escape the confines of the container and push all the way to the right edge of the browser window, and rather than taking up 50% width of the container to take up 50% width of the whole window. However I still need the first box to remain within the container taking up its original 50%. Something like so...
[image]

Any content in box 1 needs to remain both inside box 1 and also the container, whereas any content of box 2 must stay within box 2 but is not confined to the container as box 1 content is.

I've tried many different ways to achieve this with positioning and cannot solve it. I'm happy to use different MUI elements if I need to.

Example in code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-thompson-5fktk4?file=/Demo.tsx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see this can be possible is by absolutely positioning the 2nd box, that way the `body` becomes it's parent and we can give `left: 50%`

Sandbox: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-clarke-sk7p26?file=/Demo.tsx)

Hope this helps